# Memory Leak and its solutions using weak declaration in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, weak

I'm making a match-3 game using SpriteKit. [Explanation: http://www.raywenderlich.com/75273/make-game-like-candy-crush-with-swift-tutorial-part-2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/75273/make-game-like-candy-crush-with-swift-tutorial-part-2). Please refer to swm93's comment on page 4
This is a tutorial but it seems to have a memory leak in the code. Could anyone possibly download this swift project file and find what causes the memory leak and give possible solutions?
The maker of this tutorial said that there is a memory leak in "handleSwipe(swap)" method and that we can fix it by adding "weak" to field declaration. I tried to write "weak var scene: GameScene?" but if I do, it says "scene is nil" even if I initialized it like this: "scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)" in "viewDidLoad()" function.
The rest of the classes can be downloaded through my [link here](https://github.com/minsanity6/Git).
Even the view controllers have been dismissed, the memory use percentage wouldn't decrease... If I call a GameViewController, dismiss it, then call it again, the memory use is twice. In other words,
PreViewController(18MB) segue-> GameViewController(75MB) dismiss-> PreViewController(75MB) segue-> GameViewController(104MB)

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    // The scene draws the tiles and cookie sprites, and handles swipes.
    var scene: GameScene!

    // The level contains the tiles, the cookies, and most of the gameplay logic.
    // Needs to be ! because it's not set in init() but in viewDidLoad().
    var level: Level!

    var movesLeft = 0
    var score = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var targetLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var movesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gameOverPanel: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var shuffleButton: UIButton!

    var tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!

    @IBAction func dismiss(sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
    }

    lazy var backgroundMusic: AVAudioPlayer = {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Mining by Moonlight", withExtension: "mp3")
        let player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: nil)
        player.numberOfLoops = -1
        return player
        }()

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Configure the view.
        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

        // Create and configure the scene.
        scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        // Load the level.
        level = Level(filename: "Level_1")
        scene.level = level
        scene.addTiles()
        scene.swipeHandler = handleSwipe

        // Hide the game over panel from the screen.
        gameOverPanel.hidden = true
        shuffleButton.hidden = true

        // Present the scene.
        skView.presentScene(scene)

        // Load and start background music.
        backgroundMusic.play()

        // Let's start the game!
        beginGame()
    }

    func beginGame() {
        movesLeft = level.maximumMoves
        score = 0
        updateLabels()

        level.resetComboMultiplier()

        scene.animateBeginGame() {
            self.shuffleButton.hidden = false
        }

        shuffle()
    }

    func shuffle() {
        // Delete the old cookie sprites, but not the tiles.
        scene.removeAllCookieSprites()

        // Fill up the level with new cookies, and create sprites for them.
        let newCookies = level.shuffle()
        scene.addSpritesForCookies(newCookies)
    }

    // This is the swipe handler. MyScene invokes this function whenever it
    // detects that the player performs a swipe.
    func handleSwipe(swap: Swap) {
        // While cookies are being matched and new cookies fall down to fill up
        // the holes, we don't want the player to tap on anything.
        view.userInteractionEnabled = false

        if level.isPossibleSwap(swap) {
            level.performSwap(swap)
            scene.animateSwap(swap, completion: handleMatches)
        } else {
            scene.animateInvalidSwap(swap) {
                self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }

    // This is the main loop that removes any matching cookies and fills up the
    // holes with new cookies.
    func handleMatches() {
        // Detect if there are any matches left.
        let chains = level.removeMatches()

        // If there are no more matches, then the player gets to move again.
        if chains.count == 0 {
            beginNextTurn()
            return
        }

        // First, remove any matches...
        scene.animateMatchedCookies(chains) {

            // Add the new scores to the total.
            for chain in chains {
                self.score += chain.score
            }
            self.updateLabels()

            // ...then shift down any cookies that have a hole below them...
            let columns = self.level.fillHoles()
            self.scene.animateFallingCookies(columns) {

                // ...and finally, add new cookies at the top.
                let columns = self.level.topUpCookies()
                self.scene.animateNewCookies(columns) {

                    // Keep repeating this cycle until there are no more matches.
                    self.handleMatches()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func beginNextTurn() {
       level.resetComboMultiplier()
        level.detectPossibleSwaps()
        view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        decrementMoves()
    }

    func updateLabels() {
        targetLabel.text = String(format: "%ld", level.targetScore)
        movesLabel.text = String(format: "%ld", movesLeft)
        scoreLabel.text = String(format: "%ld", score)
    }

    func decrementMoves() {
        --movesLeft
        updateLabels()

        if score >= level.targetScore {
            gameOverPanel.image = UIImage(named: "LevelComplete")
            showGameOver()
        }
        else if movesLeft == 0 {
            gameOverPanel.image = UIImage(named: "GameOver")
            showGameOver()
        }
    }

    func showGameOver() {
        gameOverPanel.hidden = false
        scene.userInteractionEnabled = false
        shuffleButton.hidden = true

        scene.animateGameOver() {
            self.tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "hideGameOver")
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapGestureRecognizer)
        }
    }

    func hideGameOver() {
        view.removeGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        tapGestureRecognizer = nil

        gameOverPanel.hidden = true
        scene.userInteractionEnabled = true

        beginGame()
    }

    @IBAction func shuffleButtonPressed(AnyObject) {
        shuffle()

        // Pressing the shuffle button costs a move.
        decrementMoves()
    }
}
```

,

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    // This is marked as ! because it will not initially have a value, but pretty
    // soon after the GameScene is created it will be given a Level object, and
    // from then on it will always have one (it will never be nil again).
    var level: Level!

    var swipeHandler: ((Swap) -> ())?

    let TileWidth: CGFloat = 32.0
    let TileHeight: CGFloat = 36.0

    let gameLayer = SKNode()
    let cookiesLayer = SKNode()
    let tilesLayer = SKNode()
    let cropLayer = SKCropNode()
    let maskLayer = SKNode()

    var swipeFromColumn: Int?
    var swipeFromRow: Int?

    var selectionSprite = SKSpriteNode()

    // Pre-load the resources
    let swapSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Chomp.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
    let invalidSwapSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Error.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
    let matchSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Ka-Ching.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
    let fallingCookieSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Scrape.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
    let addCookieSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Drip.wav", waitForCompletion: false)

    // MARK: Game Setup
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder) is not used in this app")
    }

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
        addChild(background)

        gameLayer.hidden = true
        addChild(gameLayer)

        let layerPosition = CGPoint(
            x: -TileWidth * CGFloat(NumColumns) / 2,
            y: -TileHeight * CGFloat(NumRows) / 2)

        tilesLayer.position = layerPosition
        gameLayer.addChild(tilesLayer)

        // We use a crop layer to prevent cookies from being drawn across gaps
        // in the level design.
        gameLayer.addChild(cropLayer)

        // The mask layer determines which part of the cookiesLayer is visible.
        maskLayer.position = layerPosition
        cropLayer.maskNode = maskLayer

        // This layer holds the Cookie sprites. The positions of these sprites
        // are relative to the cookiesLayer's bottom-left corner.
        cookiesLayer.position = layerPosition
        cropLayer.addChild(cookiesLayer)

        // nil means that these properties have invalid values.
        swipeFromColumn = nil
        swipeFromRow = nil

        // Pre-load the label font so prevent delays during game play.
        SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "GillSans-BoldItalic")
    }

    func addSpritesForCookies(cookies: Set<Cookie>) {
        for cookie in cookies {
            // Create a new sprite for the cookie and add it to the cookiesLayer.
            let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: cookie.cookieType.spriteName)
            sprite.position = pointForColumn(cookie.column, row:cookie.row)
            cookiesLayer.addChild(sprite)
            cookie.sprite = sprite

            // Give each cookie sprite a small, random delay.
            sprite.alpha = 0
            sprite.xScale = 0.5
            sprite.yScale = 0.5

            sprite.runAction(
                SKAction.sequence([
                    SKAction.waitForDuration(0.25, withRange: 0.5),
                    SKAction.group([
                        SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.25),
                        SKAction.scaleTo(1.0, duration: 0.25)
                        ])
                    ]))
        }
    }

    func removeAllCookieSprites() {
        cookiesLayer.removeAllChildren()
    }

    func addTiles() {
        for row in 0..<NumRows {
            for column in 0..<NumColumns {

                // If there is a tile at this position, then create a new tile
                // sprite and add it to the mask layer.
                if let tile = level.tileAtColumn(column, row: row) {
                    let tileNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "MaskTile")
                    tileNode.position = pointForColumn(column, row: row)
                    maskLayer.addChild(tileNode)
                }
            }
        }

        // The tile pattern is drawn *in between* the level tiles. That's why
        // there is an extra column and row of them.
        for row in 0...NumRows {
            for column in 0...NumColumns {

                let topLeft     = (column > 0) && (row < NumRows)
                    && level.tileAtColumn(column - 1, row: row) != nil
                let bottomLeft  = (column > 0) && (row > 0)
                    && level.tileAtColumn(column - 1, row: row - 1) != nil
                let topRight    = (column < NumColumns) && (row < NumRows)
                    && level.tileAtColumn(column, row: row) != nil
                let bottomRight = (column < NumColumns) && (row > 0)
                    && level.tileAtColumn(column, row: row - 1) != nil

                // The tiles are named from 0 to 15, according to the bitmask that is
                // made by combining these four values.
                let value = Int(topLeft) | Int(topRight) << 1 | Int(bottomLeft) << 2 | Int(bottomRight) << 3

                // Values 0 (no tiles), 6 and 9 (two opposite tiles) are not drawn.
                if value != 0 && value != 6 && value != 9 {
                    let name = String(format: "Tile_%ld", value)
                    let tileNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: name)
                    var point = pointForColumn(column, row: row)
                    point.x -= TileWidth/2
                    point.y -= TileHeight/2
                    tileNode.position = point
                    tilesLayer.addChild(tileNode)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: Conversion Routines

    // Converts a column,row pair into a CGPoint that is relative to the cookieLayer.
    func pointForColumn(column: Int, row: Int) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(
            x: CGFloat(column)*TileWidth + TileWidth/2,
            y: CGFloat(row)*TileHeight + TileHeight/2)
    }

    // Converts a point relative to the cookieLayer into column and row numbers.
    func convertPoint(point: CGPoint) -> (success: Bool, column: Int, row: Int) {
        // Is this a valid location within the cookies layer? If yes,
        // calculate the corresponding row and column numbers.
        if point.x >= 0 && point.x < CGFloat(NumColumns)*TileWidth &&
            point.y >= 0 && point.y < CGFloat(NumRows)*TileHeight {
                return (true, Int(point.x / TileWidth), Int(point.y / TileHeight))
        } else {
            return (false, 0, 0)  // invalid location
        }
    }

    // MARK: Detecting Swipes

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        // Convert the touch location to a point relative to the cookiesLayer.
        let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        let location = touch.locationInNode(cookiesLayer)

        // If the touch is inside a square, then this might be the start of a
        // swipe motion.
        let (success, column, row) = convertPoint(location)
        if success {
            // The touch must be on a cookie, not on an empty tile.
            if let cookie = level.cookieAtColumn(column, row: row) {
                // Remember in which column and row the swipe started, so we can compare
                // them later to find the direction of the swipe. This is also the first
                // cookie that will be swapped.
                swipeFromColumn = column
                swipeFromRow = row

                showSelectionIndicatorForCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        // If swipeFromColumn is nil then either the swipe began outside
        // the valid area or the game has already swapped the cookies and we need
        // to ignore the rest of the motion.
        if swipeFromColumn == nil { return }

        let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        let location = touch.locationInNode(cookiesLayer)

        let (success, column, row) = convertPoint(location)
        if success {

            // Figure out in which direction the player swiped. Diagonal swipes
            // are not allowed.
            var horzDelta = 0, vertDelta = 0
            if column < swipeFromColumn! {          // swipe left
                horzDelta = -1
            } else if column > swipeFromColumn! {   // swipe right
                horzDelta = 1
            } else if row < swipeFromRow! {         // swipe down
                vertDelta = -1
            } else if row > swipeFromRow! {         // swipe up
                vertDelta = 1
            }

            // Only try swapping when the user swiped into a new square.
            if horzDelta != 0 || vertDelta != 0 {
                trySwapHorizontal(horzDelta, vertical: vertDelta)
                hideSelectionIndicator()

                // Ignore the rest of this swipe motion from now on.
                swipeFromColumn = nil
            }
        }
    }

    // We get here after the user performs a swipe. This sets in motion a whole
    // chain of events: 1) swap the cookies, 2) remove the matching lines, 3)
    // drop new cookies into the screen, 4) check if they create new matches,
    // and so on.
    func trySwapHorizontal(horzDelta: Int, vertical vertDelta: Int) {
        let toColumn = swipeFromColumn! + horzDelta
        let toRow = swipeFromRow! + vertDelta

        if toColumn < 0 || toColumn >= NumColumns { return }
        if toRow < 0 || toRow >= NumRows { return }

        // Can't swap if there is no cookie to swap with. This happens when the user
        // swipes into a gap where there is no tile.
        if let toCookie = level.cookieAtColumn(toColumn, row: toRow),
            let fromCookie = level.cookieAtColumn(swipeFromColumn!, row: swipeFromRow!),
            let handler = swipeHandler {

                // Communicate this swap request back to the ViewController.
                let swap = Swap(cookieA: fromCookie, cookieB: toCookie)
                handler(swap)
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        // Remove the selection indicator with a fade-out. We only need to do this
        // when the player didn't actually swipe.
        if selectionSprite.parent != nil && swipeFromColumn != nil {
            hideSelectionIndicator()
        }

        // If the gesture ended, regardless of whether if was a valid swipe or not,
        // reset the starting column and row numbers.
        swipeFromColumn = nil
        swipeFromRow = nil
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
    }

    // MARK: Animations

    func animateSwap(swap: Swap, completion: () -> ()) {
        let spriteA = swap.cookieA.sprite!
        let spriteB = swap.cookieB.sprite!

        // Put the cookie you started with on top.
        spriteA.zPosition = 100
        spriteB.zPosition = 90

        let Duration: NSTimeInterval = 0.3

        let moveA = SKAction.moveTo(spriteB.position, duration: Duration)
        moveA.timingMode = .EaseOut
        spriteA.runAction(moveA, completion: completion)

        let moveB = SKAction.moveTo(spriteA.position, duration: Duration)
        moveB.timingMode = .EaseOut
        spriteB.runAction(moveB)

        runAction(swapSound)
    }

    func animateInvalidSwap(swap: Swap, completion: () -> ()) {
        let spriteA = swap.cookieA.sprite!
        let spriteB = swap.cookieB.sprite!

        spriteA.zPosition = 100
        spriteB.zPosition = 90

        let Duration: NSTimeInterval = 0.2

        let moveA = SKAction.moveTo(spriteB.position, duration: Duration)
        moveA.timingMode = .EaseOut

        let moveB = SKAction.moveTo(spriteA.position, duration: Duration)
        moveB.timingMode = .EaseOut

        spriteA.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveA, moveB]), completion: completion)
        spriteB.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveB, moveA]))

        runAction(invalidSwapSound)
    }

    func animateMatchedCookies(chains: Set<Chain>, completion: () -> ()) {
        for chain in chains {
            animateScoreForChain(chain)
            for cookie in chain.cookies {

                // It may happen that the same Cookie object is part of two chains
                // (L-shape or T-shape match). In that case, its sprite should only be
                // removed once.
                if let sprite = cookie.sprite {
                    if sprite.actionForKey("removing") == nil {
                        let scaleAction = SKAction.scaleTo(0.1, duration: 0.3)
                        scaleAction.timingMode = .EaseOut
                        sprite.runAction(SKAction.sequence([scaleAction, SKAction.removeFromParent()]),
                            withKey:"removing")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        runAction(matchSound)

        runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(0.3), completion: completion)
    }

    func animateScoreForChain(chain: Chain) {
        // Figure out what the midpoint of the chain is.
        let firstSprite = chain.firstCookie().sprite!
        let lastSprite = chain.lastCookie().sprite!
        let centerPosition = CGPoint(
            x: (firstSprite.position.x + lastSprite.position.x)/2,
            y: (firstSprite.position.y + lastSprite.position.y)/2 - 8)

        let scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "GillSans-BoldItalic")
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 16
        scoreLabel.text = String(format: "%ld", chain.score)
        scoreLabel.position = centerPosition
        scoreLabel.zPosition = 300
        cookiesLayer.addChild(scoreLabel)

        let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 3), duration: 0.7)
        moveAction.timingMode = .EaseOut
        scoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveAction, SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
    }

    func animateFallingCookies(columns: [[Cookie]], completion: () -> ()) {
        var longestDuration: NSTimeInterval = 0
        for array in columns {
            for (idx, cookie) in enumerate(array) {
                let newPosition = pointForColumn(cookie.column, row: cookie.row)

                let delay = 0.05 + 0.15*NSTimeInterval(idx)

                let sprite = cookie.sprite!   

                let duration = NSTimeInterval(((sprite.position.y - newPosition.y) / TileHeight) * 0.1)
                longestDuration = max(longestDuration, duration + delay)

                let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(newPosition, duration: duration)
                moveAction.timingMode = .EaseOut
                sprite.runAction(
                    SKAction.sequence([
                        SKAction.waitForDuration(delay),
                        SKAction.group([moveAction, fallingCookieSound])]))
            }
        }

        // Wait until all the cookies have fallen down before we continue.
        runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(longestDuration), completion: completion)
    }

    func animateNewCookies(columns: [[Cookie]], completion: () -> ()) {
        // wait that amount before we trigger the completion block.
        var longestDuration: NSTimeInterval = 0

        for array in columns {

            let startRow = array[0].row + 1

            for (idx, cookie) in enumerate(array) {

                // Create a new sprite for the cookie.
                let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: cookie.cookieType.spriteName)
                sprite.position = pointForColumn(cookie.column, row: startRow)
                cookiesLayer.addChild(sprite)
                cookie.sprite = sprite

                // fall after one another.
                let delay = 0.1 + 0.2 * NSTimeInterval(array.count - idx - 1)

                // Calculate duration based on far the cookie has to fall.
                let duration = NSTimeInterval(startRow - cookie.row) * 0.1
                longestDuration = max(longestDuration, duration + delay)
                let newPosition = pointForColumn(cookie.column, row: cookie.row)
                let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(newPosition, duration: duration)
                moveAction.timingMode = .EaseOut
                sprite.alpha = 0
                sprite.runAction(
                    SKAction.sequence([
                        SKAction.waitForDuration(delay),
                        SKAction.group([
                            SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.05),
                            moveAction,
                            addCookieSound])
                        ]))
            }
        }

        // Wait until the animations are done before we continue.
        runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(longestDuration), completion: completion)
    }

    func animateGameOver(completion: () -> ()) {
        let action = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -size.height), duration: 0.3)
        action.timingMode = .EaseIn
        gameLayer.runAction(action, completion: completion)
    }

    func animateBeginGame(completion: () -> ()) {
        gameLayer.hidden = false
        gameLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: size.height)
        let action = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -size.height), duration: 0.3)
        action.timingMode = .EaseOut
        gameLayer.runAction(action, completion: completion)
    }

    // MARK: Selection Indicator

    func showSelectionIndicatorForCookie(cookie: Cookie) {
        if selectionSprite.parent != nil {
            selectionSprite.removeFromParent()
        }

        if let sprite = cookie.sprite {
            let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: cookie.cookieType.highlightedSpriteName)
            selectionSprite.size = texture.size()
            selectionSprite.runAction(SKAction.setTexture(texture))

            sprite.addChild(selectionSprite)
            selectionSprite.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }

    func hideSelectionIndicator() {
        selectionSprite.runAction(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.3),
            SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting `scene` to `weak` is causing it to be nil because the only reference to is is a weak one, so it gets deallocated as soon as possible afterwards.  The memory leak the author is referencing is probably a reference cycle within a closure which is fixed by making the local variable `weak` or `unowned`.

Comment: @Skrundz Thanks, I think you meant "reference cycle within a closure" as [weak self], correct? If so, which closure should I write this?